# What is a "supplementary subspace"?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $Q$ be a quadratic form of vector space $V$ over a field $k$ with characteristic $\neq 2 $, $V^{0}$ be its orthogonal complement.

> If $U$ is a *supplementary subspace* of $V^0$ in $V$, then $V = U \oplus V^0$ .

What does *supplementaty subspace* mean in above proposition? This is s a proposition in Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*, and it only says that it's clear to prove, but never defines what a supplementary subspace is.

Comment: It does not define it. If you can't find the original French version, I recommend Cassels *Rational Quadratic Forms,* which fits most of the questions on MSE about quadratic forms that I see.

Comment: I think "complementary subspace" (Eng.) = "sous-espace supplémentaire" (French), and this was badly translated. The highlighted statement would just be the definition of supplémentaire.

Comment: I think that "complementary subspace" is a misleading terminology (since it's not the set-wise complement), and therefore I support rather using "supplementary". It sounds very plausible that the author (Serre) chose himself the translation, to avoid "complementary".

Comment: @YCor  (I know this is coming a few years late) in English the term "complementary subspace" is standard, and it's far more commonly used than "supplementary subspace". Yes, it is not the set-theoretic complement, but that wouldn't be a subspace anyway, so there's no problem. Also, math terms are not always strictly logical: elliptic curves are not ellipses (the term just reflects the history of that concept). The term "complementary subspace" also nicely compliments (pun intended) the term "orthogonal complement".  In French you don't say supplément orthogonal, right?

Comment: @YCor I agree it is very likely that Serre chose the term "supplementary subspace", since it appears Serre translated the book into English himself: nobody is listed as a translator either in the book or in the MathSciNet review of the English translation, in contrast to the English translations of his books *Local Fields* and *Galois Cohomology*.

Comment: @KCd in French we say "orthogonal" or "supplémentaire orthogonal".

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no answer, here is what I think the correct interpretation is:

If $U,U'$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then $U'$ is **supplementary** to $U$ iff $U\oplus U' = V$, in the sense that $U\cap U' = 0$ and $U + U' = V$.

With this definition, contrary to Marc van Leeuwen's comment, I think the statement of Serre is not totally trivial: all you need to show is that you have orthogonality of the subspaces.